# FAILED! => {"msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named 'winrm'"}

Tags: ansible

I am working on ansible and windows vm(windows server 2019) and getting the error above.
I have added `python3 -m pip install --user --ignore-installed pywinrm` in the yml steps too.

**  - script: |
echo Installing $(caCertificate.secureFilePath) to the trusted CA directory...
chown root:root $(caCertificate.secureFilePath)
chmod a+r $(caCertificate.secureFilePath)
python3 -m pip install testresources
python3 -m pip install --user --ignore-installed pywinrm
**

error log:
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [host1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named 'winrm'"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
host1                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

##[error]Command ansible-playbook -i /home/vsts/work/1/s/inventories/production/windows_hosts /home/vsts/work/1/s/site.yml  exited with code 2.
Finishing: Ansible

Extremely new to Ansible

Comment: please check this link out : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3356681

Comment: i have tried this one too but not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you please run `ansible --version`. The last line should confirm if you are using Python 2 or Python 3, ie:

```
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) [GCC 9.2.1 20191008]
```

Can you confirm that you've run `pip3` on the same machine you are running `ansible-controller`

So in my case I'd need to use `pip2`